# using two functions in same class

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

The startFunction has a task to call the doFunction for 3 seconds, and then to stop. Unfortunatly that doesn't work without any compiler error. Just blank output. Probably some easy mistake, but i'm a beginner and can't find the solution since few hours. I've cut the code to make it more clear, but can paste if necessary.

```
    package  {
        //all imports

        public class MemoryPuzzles extends MovieClip{
            //all variables


            public function MemoryPuzzles():void {//first function

 //function memory puzzles
                }//first function end end


    public function startFunction():void//beginning of second function in the single class
    {
                    trace("start function works");

    startTime = getTimer();
    if( (getTimer() - startTime)<3000 ){
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, doFunction);
    } else {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, doFunction);
    }

    function doFunction(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("do function works");
    }//end of dofunction
    }//end of startfunction
    }//class end
}//import end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer a following code. i tested.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

        public class MemoryPuzzles extends MovieClip
        {

            public function MemoryPuzzles():void 
            {
                startFunction();
            }

            public function startFunction():void
            {
                trace("start function works");

                var startTime = getTimer();
                addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, doFunction);
                function doFunction(e:Event):void
                {
                    trace("time: " + (int)(getTimer()-startTime));
                    if((int)(getTimer()-startTime)>=3000)
                    {
                        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, doFunction);
                        trace("ended");
                    } 
                }
            }
       }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. What do you recommend for learning actionscript's basics?

Comment: books: [Essential-AS3.0](http://www.amazon.com/Essential-ActionScript-3-0-Colin-Moock/dp/0596526946/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1346717585&sr=8-1&keywords=actionscript+3), [Learning-AS3.0](http://www.amazon.com/Learning-ActionScript-3-0-Rich-Shupe/dp/144939017X/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1346717585&sr=8-4&keywords=actionscript+3) site: [adobe_official_Developer's_Guide](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/index.html), [flash_and_math](http://www.flashandmath.com/)

Comment: I recommend the topic starter to use this type of indenting (like @bitmapdata.com did), so you can quickly spot when you're missing brackets.